# How to trigger functions of Autodesk.Viewing.Extension Class from outside?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I would like to trigger functions of Autodesk.Viewing.Extension Class from outside of the class.

For example

PinMarkExtension.js

```
class PinMarkExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
  constructor(viewer, options) {
    super(viewer, options);
  }

  someFunc () {
    ...
  }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('PinMarkExtension', PinMarkExtension);
```

ObjectViewer.js

```
.
.
.
  this.$Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, async() => {
    const viewerDiv = document.getElementById("viewer")
    const config = {
      extensions: ['PinMarkExtension']
    };
    this.viewer = new this.$Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv, config)
    this.viewer.start()

    this.$Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load( 
      documentId,
      this.onDocumentLoadSuccess,
      this.onDocumentLoadFailure
    )

    this.viewer.loadExtension('PinMarkExtension', {
      initialValues: [...]
    })
  })
.
.
.
  // After extension loaded
  // WANT TO TRIGGER someFunc Here
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can get loaded extension instance through getExtension(extensionId, callback) API of Viewer3D so you can invoke someFunc() e.g. like below sample.

```
viewer.getExtension('PinMarkExtension', (extension) => {
                extension.someFunc();
            });
```

Comment: I would suggest to use the return value of the `getExtension` method instead. If the extension does not exist or is not loaded, the return value will be `null`, but the callback function will *not* be called.